# C++ pointer to be deferenced before using it

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I've defined a variables in a class

```
const char* info;


bool machine::ping(){
     if(info[0] == '\0' ){
        printf("%s", "null");
     }
     else{
        printf("%s",info); <---------- This does NOT print out what I expect. :(
     }
}

bool machine::RecvNotify(const Data& aData){
     info = aData.path();
     printf("%s",info);  <------- This works well and prints out what I expect
}
```

I guess I can not define this variable this way. Please let me know if there is something I should change. Thanks

Comment: `info` points into the storage of whatever `aData` refers to. Probably the error is because that object was destroyed before you got to calling `machine::ping()`.   Instead you should use `std::string info;`

Comment: Agree, would you mind explain why sdt::string info can avoid been killed before calling to ping() function ?

Comment: a `std::string` stores a string; if it's a member of the `machine` class then it still exists so long as the object containing it exists. `char const *info` does not store a string; it points to where some other part of the program is storing a string.

Comment: thanks. I just found that printf does not have member for std::string type, i need to use std::out to get the output, what headers I should include in this case?

Comment: Thanks, it works! unfortunately some people think this question does not make any sense so I might delete it later. Thank you Matt.

Comment: You can also use printf with an std::string: printf("%s", string.c_str())

Comment: yea, thanks Jan. but some people think this question does not make any sense so I might delete it later.

Comment: @Sam to make the question good you should post a MCVE. As things stand people have to make a lot of guesses about what's going on in the code you didn't show.

Comment: @Matt, thanks. I've modified the topic for this question. Not sure about what's MCVE.

Comment: search for MCVE on stackoverflow

Comment: Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is fine, but aData.path might return only a temporary string, depending on the implementation.

What happens if you change `const char* info` to `std::string`?

Comment: agree, i am sure it's a temp string which I want to save it to become a permanent one. that's my intention.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things.

First,  **"machine::RecvNotify()" should be called before "machine::ping()"**. This is to give "info" an address to point into.

Second, in "machine::RecvNotify()", **is "aData" still in scope** when you called "machine::ping()". If not, "info" will have and invalid address to point to when you call "machine::ping()". This may have caused your "unexpected output".

If you want to be able to have the value of "aData.path()" even if it is no longer in scope, you may copy its value.
As suggested, you may copy value to a std::string member variable.